# Get elements from an array based on array containing indices

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays:

1- `inventory` that contains some elements

2- `indices_dates` that contains the indices of the elements I want from `inventory`.

Is there a simple way to create an array formed by the elements of `inventory` if their index is contained into `indices_dates`

Example:

```
let inventory
let indices_dates
let final = []

inventory = [25, 35, 40, 20, 15, 17]
indices_dates = [0, 2, 3, 5]
---Some Code To Get Final Array---
```

**The output  I would like:**

```
final = [25, 40, 20, 17]
```

I did the following:

```
let inventory
let indices_dates
let final = []
let i

inventory = [25, 35, 40, 20, 15, 17]
indices_dates = [0, 2, 3, 5]

for (i in indices_dates) {
    final.push(inventory[indices_dates[i]])
}
```

But I am wondering if there is another, more direct way to achieve it.

Comment: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: your solution seems ok to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Array.map()` to iterate the indices array, and take the values from `inventory`:

```js
const inventory = [25, 35, 40, 20, 15, 17]
const indices_dates = [0, 2, 3, 5]
const final = indices_dates.map(idx => inventory[idx])

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as @Ori suggest or alternative solution is :

Another approach is using **forEach** :

```js
const inventory = [25, 35, 40, 20, 15, 17]
const indices_dates = [0, 2, 3, 5];
let final = [];
indices_dates.forEach(data => final.push(inventory[data]))
console.log(final)
```

Using **for of** :

```js
const inventory = [25, 35, 40, 20, 15, 17]
const indices_dates = [0, 2, 3, 5];
let final = [];

for (let dateIndex of indices_dates){
final.push(inventory[dateIndex])
}
console.log(final)
```